# Set authentication-token-webhook-config-file

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

My goal is to set appscode guard application.
In order to so i need to set the value of authentication-token-webhook-config-file flag in Kubernetes api server.

How to do that ?

Comment: There are pretty detailed guides about it available: https://appscode.com/products/guard/0.2.1/setup/install/#configure-kubernetes-api-server and here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#webhook-token-authentication Which step is unclear for you?

Comment: Error: Application with identifier 'XXXX' was not found in the directory ''YYYY". This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the way to add an option key to `kube-apiserver` pod on existing cluster, you just need to edit file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` **on master node**.

After saving this file, `kube-apiserver` pod will be restarted by `kubelet` service automatically.

Considering that flag you've mentioned has to have name of the configuration file as parameter, ensure the file exists on the master node file system.

```
--authentication-token-webhook-config-file string
File with webhook configuration for token authentication in kubeconfig format. The API server will query the remote service to determine authentication for bearer tokens.
```

The directory for the manifests is defined by kubelet option `--pod-manifest-path` and can be found using command:

```
$ ps aux | grep kubelet
```

You can find more information about life cycle of such pods in [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/static-pod/)